# HomeActivity must implement AlertPositiveListener

Tags: java, android

As i'm fresher in the android, So please help me out. When the  Imagebutton is clicked, alert Dialog window with radio buttons will be shown. Here is the code below I have used to get the alert dialog box.

PhotosAdapter.java:

```
reportAbuseImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    FragmentManager manager = ((Activity) mCtx).getFragmentManager();

                    AlertDialogRadio alert = new AlertDialogRadio();                         
                    Bundle b  = new Bundle();                            
                    b.putInt("position", position);                          
                    alert.setArguments(b);    
                    alert.show(manager, "alert_dialog_radio");
                }
            });
```

AlertDialogRadio.java:

```
public class AlertDialogRadio extends DialogFragment {


    AlertPositiveListener alertPositiveListener;            
    public interface AlertPositiveListener {
        public void onPositiveClick(int position);
    }

    public void setListener(AlertPositiveListener alertPositiveListener){
        this.alertPositiveListener=alertPositiveListener;
    }

    public void onAttach(android.app.Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try{
            alertPositiveListener = (AlertPositiveListener) activity;
        }catch(ClassCastException e){

            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement AlertPositiveListener");
        }
    }


    OnClickListener positiveListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            AlertDialog alert = (AlertDialog)dialog;
            int position = alert.getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
            alertPositiveListener.onPositiveClick(position);
        }
    };


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        int position = bundle.getInt("position");


        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());              
        b.setTitle("Choose your version");          
        b.setSingleChoiceItems(RadioButtonList.Android.code, position, null);

        b.setPositiveButton("OK",positiveListener);                
        b.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);            
        AlertDialog d = b.create();               
        return d;
    }
}
```

Android.java:

```
public class Android {
    static String[] code = new String[]{
            "Not Intrested",
            "Sexual Content",
            "Violent or repulsive content",
            "Spam or misleading",
            "Infringes my rights",
            "Wrong description",
            "Description is not complete"
    };
}
```

Unfortunately, when the Imagebutton is clicked, the app crashed.

LogCatError:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.splash.indivillage.indishare, PID: 10084
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.splash.indivillage.indishare.Home.HomeActivity@e7e35e6 must implement AlertPositiveListener
                      at com.splash.indivillage.indishare.Utils.AlertDialogRadio.onAttach(AlertDialogRadio.java:37)
                      at android.app.Fragment.onAttach(Fragment.java:1454)
                      at android.app.DialogFragment.onAttach(DialogFragment.java:365)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:937)
                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:860)
                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:883)
                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:728)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1580)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6205)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Edited:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Vc5.jpg)

Please help me out. Thanking You.

Comment: read the comment before the line where crash is coming

Comment: alt+ent on click and implement interface method.

Answer (score 1):

As error suggested you have to implement AlertPositiveListener in your HomeActivity where you are using your AlertDialog

```
HomeActivity implements AlertPositiveListener
```

And then you have to override methods declared in interface to your home activity.

```
@Override
public void onPositiveClick(int position){
// implement your code here
}
```

Check [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/interface-in-java) to how interface works.

Comment: By adding the implements it is showing the same error.

Comment: error must be about overriding method that are declared in your interface . override that method in your homeactivity. check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You are casting Activity's context into an `Interface` reference variable and there is  no relation between Parent `Activity` and `AlertPositiveListener`.

Solution can be multiple. Do not go with Casting implement `AlertPositiveListener` in your Activity.

```
HomeActivity implements AlertDialogListener{
@Override
public void onPositiveClick(int position){
// Do your stuff
  }
 }
```

and set listener as follows before transaction.

```
AlertDialogRadio alert = new AlertDialogRadio();
 alert.setListener(this)
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("position",position);
alert.setArguments(b);
alert.show(manager,"alert_dialog_radio");
```

Then just use the `alertPositiveListener` for callback no need of casting.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting error because you have to override interface method in your fragment.interface method is `onPositiveClick(int position)`

```
 HomeActivity implements AlertDialogListener{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
    container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         AlertDialogRadio alert = new AlertDialogRadio();
         alert.setListener(this)
        }

        @Override
        public void onPositiveClick(int position){
         //this method you have to override
        }   
      }
```

Hope it will help you!!